# Problem with memory usage in Centos VPS

Tags: linux, centos

Recently I bought my third VPS with the same or even higher quality

Centos 5.6

Kloxo 6.1.6

Server Spec :

1500 MB RAM 
4 CORE INTEL

But on this vps the memory usage is oddly high and I can't find any solution to fix this

this is the process list after restarting my vps :

```
 3180        600.49  mysql   /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/
     10904       41.14   apache  /usr/sbin/httpd
     10905       38.96   apache  /usr/sbin/httpd
     10903       36.5    apache  /usr/sbin/httpd
     10907       35.44   apache  /usr/sbin/httpd
     10906       35.44   apache  /usr/sbin/httpd
     3047        35.2    lxpopuser   spamd child
     10901       35.17   root    /usr/sbin/httpd
     3048        34.28   lxpopuser   spamd child
     3016        34  root    /usr/bin/spamd --min-spare=2 -d -p 783 -x -u lxpopuser --virtual-config-dir=/home/lxadmin/mail/spama
     10813       27.59   root    /usr/local/lxlabs/ext/php/php ../sbin/kloxo.php master
     2948        26.72   root    automount
     3601        25.29   root    /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/sbin/yum-updatesd
     2185        21.93   root    brcm_iscsiuio
     2858        12.53   root    pcscd
     2459        12.33   root    auditd
     2461        11.88   root    /sbin/audispd
     2985        10  root    cupsd
     10356       9.82    root    sshd: root@pts/0
     2972        7.04    root    /usr/sbin/sshd
     3330        6.96    root    /usr/libexec/courier-authlib/authdaemond
     3255        6.91    root    /usr/libexec/courier-authlib/authdaemond
     10785       5.94    lxlabs  /usr/local/lxlabs/ext/lxlighttpd/sbin/kloxo.httpd -f /usr/local/lxlabs/kloxo/file/lighttpd.conf
     2679        5.8     root    rpc.idmapd
     3286        5.26    root    crond
     10821       4.81    qmailr  qmail-remote yahoo.com postmaster@mysite.com alireza_rahmat_ie@yahoo.com
     10746       4.81    qmailr  qmail-remote yahoo.com postmaster@mysite.com hosseini_re@yahoo.com
     10846       4.81    qmailr  qmail-remote yahoo.com postmaster@my.mysite2.net mxxx@yahoo.com
     10830       4.81    qmailr  qmail-remote ymail.com postmaster@mysite.com mxxx@ymail.com
     3056        4.52    root    sh ../sbin/kloxo-wrapper.sh
     10369       4.52    root    -bash
     3133        4.52    root    /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --log-error
     2191        4.06    root    iscsid
     3181        3.7     root    logger -p daemon.err -t mysqld_safe -i -t mysqld
     2190        3.61    root    iscsid
     3531        3.53    root    /usr/sbin/smartd -q never
     2768        2.78    dbus    dbus-daemon --system
     3002        2.77    root    xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid
     3603        2.59    root    /usr/libexec/gam_server
     2571        2.5     root    irqbalance
     652         2.34    root    /sbin/udevd -d
     3313        2.3     root    /usr/sbin/atd
     2781        2.2     root    /usr/sbin/hcid
     1       2.11    root    init [3]
     2908        1.96    root    /usr/bin/hidd --server
     10647       1.96    qmails  qmail-send
     2647        1.92    root    rpc.statd
     2602        1.87    rpc     portmap
     3032        1.82    tinydns     /usr/local/bin/tinydns
     2785        1.79    root    /usr/sbin/sdpd
     9023        1.77    root    syslogd -m 0
     3033        1.75    root    tcpserver -vDRHl0 -x tcp.cdb -- 0.0.0.0 53 /usr/local/bin/axfrdns
     3260        1.75    root    /usr/bin/tcpserver -v -R -H -l dl.myserver.com 0 110 /usr/sbin/pop3login /usr/bin/pop3d Maildir
     3274        1.75    root    /usr/bin/tcpserver -v -R -H -l dl.myserver.com 0 993 /usr/bin/couriertls -server -tcpd /usr/sbin/im
     3264        1.75    root    /usr/bin/tcpserver -v -R -H -l dl.myserver.com 0 995 /usr/bin/couriertls -server -tcpd /usr/sbin/po
     3270        1.75    root    /usr/bin/tcpserver -v -R -H -l dl.myserver.com 0 143 /usr/sbin/imaplogin /usr/bin/imapd Maildir
     10650       1.73    root    qmail-lspawn |preline procmail
     9026        1.72    root    klogd -x
     2872        1.72    root    /usr/sbin/acpid
     10651       1.72    qmailr  qmail-rspawn
     10652       1.71    qmailq  qmail-clean
     10649       1.71    qmaill  splogger qmail
     3534        1.71    root    /sbin/mingetty tty1
     3535        1.71    root    /sbin/mingetty tty2
     3537        1.71    root    /sbin/mingetty tty4
     3539        1.71    root    /sbin/mingetty tty5
     3540        1.71    root    /sbin/mingetty tty6
     3536        1.71    root    /sbin/mingetty tty3
```

can you see anything odd that can be the cause of my high memory usage problem ?

Comment: You can check which process is eating your RAM with `# ps -eo pmem,pid,comm | sort -k1rn | head`?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem here. Everything is fine. More physical RAM means more buffering and caching. So you see less "available" RAM. Why this is wrong is explained here: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

From your "screenshot" one can see that 600 Megs are used by MySQL and another 200 by Apache (PHP?).

So it seems that you have an application that uses more memory than the applications on the other VPS. They aren't the same application, are they?

Comment: yes the are the same , but they took 150 mb ram . I suspect that it might be a problem with caching size .. how to decrease it . meanwhile my websites are so lazy slow.